# Pytorch Unable to download Dataset

Tags: python, pytorch

I am currently trying to use WikiTest103 dataset from the pytorch torchtext module.
When I try to run the below code, I get the error as:

```
from torchtext.datasets import WikiText103
X_train= WikiText103()
print(X_train.shape)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Freiburg/MasterProject/TestWikiText103.py", line 2, in <module>
    X_train= WikiText103()
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'path' and 'text_field'
```

However,
When I run the same piece of code on Google Colab, it works perfectly.
My torchtext version is 0.8.1 and pytorch version is 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by upgrading `torchtext` to version `0.11.0` with:

```
 pip install torchtext --upgrade
```